# Deleting a section of file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I couldn't think of a solution in bash that could delete a section of a file and hence I am posting it here and looking for help.

so I have a file that looks like this:

```
track type=wiggle_0 name= description=
variableStep chrom=chr1
10203   3
10213   4
10223   5
10233   5
10243   4
10253   3
10263   3
10366   6
10376   10
track type=wiggle_0 name= description=
variableStep chrom=chr2
10203   3
10213   4
10223   5
10233   5
10263   3
10366   6
10376   10
track type=wiggle_0 name= description=
variableStep chrom=chr3
10203   3
10213   4
10223   5
10233   5
10243   4
10253   3
track type=wiggle_0 name= description=
variableStep chrom=chrM
10203   3
10213   4
10223   5
10233   5
10243   4
10253   3
10263   3
10366   6
10376   10
track type=wiggle_0 name= description=
variableStep chrom=chrX
10203   3
10213   4
10223   5
10233   5
10243   4
10253   3
10263   3
10366   6
10376   10
```

I want to delete/remove the section

```
track type=wiggle_0 name= description=
    variableStep chrom=chrM
    10203   3
    10213   4
    10223   5
    10233   5
    10243   4
    10253   3
    10263   3
    10366   6
    10376   10
```

should be possible using a combination of 
grep and cut but can't figure it out.

Just to clear it, I want to delete the block containing chrM

Thank you in advance for any solutions.

Note: What I am doing

```
$ cat tst.awk /^track/ { track=$0 ORS; next } /chrom/  { f=(/chrM/ ? 1 : 0) } if { print track $0; track="" }
```

and I get the error:

```
 bash: !f: event not found
```

Comment: What's your criteria for selecting that block for removal? 4th block, 2nd-last block, block containing chrM, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on one possible interpretation of your requirements (that you want to delete the block containing `chrM`), this will work using any awk in any shell on any UNIX box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^track/ { track=$0 ORS; next }
/chrom/  { f=(/chrM/ ? 1 : 0) }
!f { print track $0; track="" }
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
track type=wiggle_0 name= description=
variableStep chrom=chr1
10203   3
10213   4
10223   5
10233   5
10243   4
10253   3
10263   3
10366   6
10376   10
track type=wiggle_0 name= description=
variableStep chrom=chr2
10203   3
10213   4
10223   5
10233   5
10263   3
10366   6
10376   10
track type=wiggle_0 name= description=
variableStep chrom=chr3
10203   3
10213   4
10223   5
10233   5
10243   4
10253   3
track type=wiggle_0 name= description=
variableStep chrom=chrX
10203   3
10213   4
10223   5
10233   5
10243   4
10253   3
10263   3
10366   6
10376   10
```

Comment: The interpretation is correct. However I get following error -bash: !f: event not found

Comment: I have done exactly what you wrote and I still get same error. The exclamation mark in command? is it ok to put ! in bash like (!f)

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check. I am sure it is something at my end, but what?

Comment: Thank's Ed. It was stupid me. I should have noticed that cat doesn't work like that. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gnu awk` as this:

```
kw='track type=wiggle_0 name= description='
awk -v kw="$kw" -v RS="$kw[[:space:]]*" -v ORS= 'NR>1 && !/^variableStep chrom=chrM/{print kw "\n" $0}' file
```

**Output:**

```
track type=wiggle_0 name= description=
variableStep chrom=chr1
10203   3
10213   4
10223   5
10233   5
10243   4
10253   3
10263   3
10366   6
10376   10
track type=wiggle_0 name= description=
variableStep chrom=chr2
10203   3
10213   4
10223   5
10233   5
10263   3
10366   6
10376   10
track type=wiggle_0 name= description=
variableStep chrom=chr3
10203   3
10213   4
10223   5
10233   5
10243   4
10253   3
track type=wiggle_0 name= description=
variableStep chrom=chrX
10203   3
10213   4
10223   5
10233   5
10243   4
10253   3
10263   3
10366   6
10376   10
```

Answer (score 0):

Unified **`awk`** solution:

```
awk '/^track type=wiggle_0 name= description=/{ if (f) f=0; t=$0; n=NR+1; next }
     n && NR==n{ 
         if (/variableStep chrom=chrM/) { f=1; next }
         else { print t; f=t=n=0 }
     }
     f{ next }1' file
```

The output:

```
track type=wiggle_0 name= description=
variableStep chrom=chr1
10203   3
10213   4
10223   5
10233   5
10243   4
10253   3
10263   3
10366   6
10376   10
track type=wiggle_0 name= description=
variableStep chrom=chr2
10203   3
10213   4
10223   5
10233   5
10263   3
10366   6
10376   10
track type=wiggle_0 name= description=
variableStep chrom=chr3
10203   3
10213   4
10223   5
10233   5
10243   4
10253   3
track type=wiggle_0 name= description=
variableStep chrom=chrX
10203   3
10213   4
10223   5
10233   5
10243   4
10253   3
10263   3
10366   6
10376   10
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **sed**:

```
sed -n '/variableStep chrom=chrM/,/10376   10/\!p' file | uniq
```

1) `sed -n '/str1/,/str2/\!p' file`

2) `-n` - for silent

3) `//,//p` - used for getting section between str1 & str2 using **`\!`** will get the all file excluding the ection between str1 & str2

4) `uniq` - remove `"track type=wiggle_0 name= description="` extra line after removing line will be written twice

Comment: Using GNU sed 4.4 in bash on cygwin - `sed: -e expression #1, char 67: unknown command: `\'`. Also that general approach would fail if the chrM block was the last one in the file.

Comment: thanks to Ed Morton i have fixed it :)

Comment: You're welcome but it still generates a syntax error - `$ sed -n '/variableStep chrom=chrM/,/10376   10/\!p' file` -> 
`sed: -e expression #1, char 39: unknown command: '\'`. Obviously it's also now dependent on `10376   10` appearing at the end of the chrM block and not appearing elsewhere in it so YMMV.

Comment: You shouldn't escape `!`, that's what causes the error. Are you using csh? In csh, you *do* have to escape it. In Bash, you don't.